# Visual Studio 2017 .sql files now building and error. How to disable

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm working on a MVC ASP.NET project.  The database sql files are in a project of their own so they can be worked on and version controlled but they aren't to be managed by Visual Studio.  They used to build and have errors.  Rather than working out the errors we simply decided to stop these files building.  I achieved this by changing the `Build Action` of it to `None`.

I've just upgraded VS to the latest 15.5.4 with various additional installed products and now the sql files are building again despite the build action remaining at `None`.  And giving build errors.

The additional installed products include:

- SQL Server Data Tools - 15.1.61710.120

I assume it was upgraded and is behind this problem.

Does anyone know what is causing these files to build when they shouldn't?  And how to stop?

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer is to unload the project:

1. Select project in Solution Explorer
2. menus > Project > unload project

This requires needing to reload the project to work on it.  Which is less than ideal.